Dynamically create devices in Virtual HID driver
For a project I want to create a Virtual HID driver that can dynamically create devices based on report descriptors provided by the software utilizing the driver. Would this be possible, and if yes how? Just to get a feel of the scope: these report descriptors might be transmitted over a network in later iterations.
I have had significant trouble figuring out how to create Virtual HID Drivers and just managed to get a sample project running that produces a touch input on command. I have experimented some with that project but can't figure out if it is possible to do something like that.
